# Is there a word that represents both a rant and a musing?

Tags: single-word-requests

Today, I unconsciously used the word 'pseudo making sense'.
But what I had really been looking for, was a word that combines 'rant' and 'musing'. In this particular case, I was saying something that was probably scientifically baseless or a half-truth for the purpose of humor and reflection.

I feel this is already something done a lot and I'm wondering if there's any such word that fits the particular case of creating humor and 'food for thought' with a short writing.

Answer (score 1):

One term that might suit your description is **soliloquy**, which *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines as

> **1 :** the act of talking to oneself **2 :** a dramatic monologue that represents a series of unspoken reflections

A soliloquy can be spoken or unspoken and can be reflective or polemical. A silent version of a soliloquy is sometimes referred to as an *internal monologue*.

Comment: The second definition would have been suitable but definitely not referring to the case of speaking to oneself. The reflection is presented for the purpose of the listener(s) and in a way that it can be remembered using humor or maybe some other tool.

Comment: Then maybe the phrase "a didactic farrago"? Here, _didactic_ can mean "**1 a :** designed or intended to teach **b :** intended to convey instruction and information as well as pleasure and entertainment **2 :** making moral observations" and _farrago_ simply means "a confused mixture : HODGEPODGE" (All definitions from Merriam-Webster).

Comment: Haha nice, I think that fits. Funny enough Google definition gives an example use of farrago as "a farrago of fact and myth about Abraham Lincoln". This is another related use case and I may be easily and more specifically translated as say, a 'didactic farrago on Abraham Lincoln's life as a republican.' no?

Answer (score 0):

Were you not being [***facetious***?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/facetious?searchDictCode=all)

> Treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humor

In this sense a facetious remark is sarcastic humor that often suggests a simple, if unthinkable, solution to a complex problem:

- "Well, we can just disregard that result.  It's clearly impossible."
- "Maybe we can just send them a suitcase of cash"

A favorite of mine from a university electrical engineering class:

- "I see your problem.  The ground wire isn't black."

Answer (score 0):

O think what you may be looking for is Pontificate. Those who pontificate are often spouting platidues or are bloviating windbags.

Answer (score 0):

‘**Thinking out-loud’.**

It means ‘sharing thoughts which are as yet unformed into an argument, theory, or completed idea or artwork’.

Example:

‘What on earth do you mean, we should paint the living room purple, with pink hearts, green polka dots and orange stripes?’

‘Oh - I was just thinking out loud!’

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/think-out-loud_2

You could also call it ‘a cogitation’ - a ‘piece of thought’.

**More creative ideas:**

As a description for your humourous, yet unformed piece of writing... you could call it ‘a smorgasbord of delicious ideas’ or a ‘patchwork’, or maybe a ‘treasury of half-baked concepts’ or a ‘treasure chest of earthly delights’. A jumble. A rainbow pudding. A confection of...

as it’s ‘food for thought’ then maybe ‘food’ could feature.

Soul food. Creative nourishment. Inspirational snacks. The artful gourmet.

Maybe that will spark something.